# Can't add options on Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium for scraping and I can't add options to my Web driver. Does this happen to anybody else? If so could you please help me fix this problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable_notifications")

chromeDriver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

This is the error I'm getting when I run the script:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'path'
```

Comment: can you try explicitly specify the Chrome WebDriver path like below?
`chromeDriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver', options=options)`